# Rspec tests passing without actions being implemented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, rspec-rails, vagrant

Hi there am working on a rails project, using a vagrant box(with ubuntu server fully configured with passenger, trying a hand at developing on a production like environment because this is my target production environment).

My problem though is that when i run "rails g controller people" and i write a simple controller spec like;

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PeopleController do
  describe "GET #index" do
    it "responds with success" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end
end
```

and i run it with "rspec spec/controllers/", the test passes right away even without having created an index action in the controller.

What do you think could be causing this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there an index.html.erb in app/views/people? If so Rails implicitly creates an action for you that renders the template.